# How do i get deep link after user install the app through firebase dynamic link and opens the app on app drawer?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, invite, dynamic-links

i'm using firebase dynamic links to invite friends to my app. Everything works great. Clicking the invitation link leads me to the playstore. When i install the app and wait until its done the playstore shows me the button "Continue". 
When i click this button, the app opens and i receive the deeplink to track the invitation.

But when i install the app, close the playstore and open the app through the app drawer i'm NOT receiving the deeplink.

Is this an expected behavior?

My problem is, that i'm looking for the invitation link only on first app start. so when the user installs my app through an invitation link but don't open it with the playstore continue button, the invitation never gets tracked.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Which version of the dynamic links SDK are you using?

Comment: Hi, currently i'm using firebase version 11.8.0

Comment: This shouldn't happen - is there anything you are doing that might mean it the fdl code path doesn't get hit if launched from the app drawer? Do you have logging for that situation?

Comment: No. In both cases the same code is executed. At first i try to find the dynamic link with 'FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().getDynamicLink(intent)' If this isn't returning any data i try to get the intent data and check this for the dynamic link. Do you have any suggestions what i can try. Testing this isn't easy because i always have to release a version to the playstore. Or are there any other options to test this?

Comment: Similar Situation here (https://stackoverflow.com/q/52077517/4754141)